# Есть ли возможность вернуть иходный код функции php?

Tags: php

Сразу уточню, я где-то об этом читал, то ли это было нестандартное расширение для php, то ли такая возможность существует, просто не могу найти. Если кто знает или уверен, что мне померещилось подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Хм, это был бы конец Zend Guarg'а)

Comment: Почему бы это? :)

Comment: Ну, `get_defined_vars`, `get_defined_constants` и так по сути потрошат весь шифр, а с такой штукой придется писать код как на паскале в школе - без функций и констант, а потом переменные еще обнулять.

Answer (score 1):

Через [Reflection](http://php.net/class.reflectionfunction) можно узнать путь к файлу, номера первой и последней строк определения функции. А дальше уже дело техники: file(), array_slice(), implode().